# Find driver modules used by my application

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, objdump

I want to know all the driver modules used by my running application. Is there any way to check this.? Something like objdump used to find dependent libraries / binaries.

Comment: Might be, that there is something. But please go to superuser so site, this one is only for programming-topics.

Comment: `lsof` and `fuser` can be first tools to try.